# Evaluating a String corresponding to the name of a class/instance field

Tags: java, opencv

In the Java OpenCV API a FeatureDetector is created using the following factory method:

```
public static FeatureDetector create(int detectorType)
```

where `detectorType` corresponds to a `static final int` field of the same class `FeatureDetector`, for example `FeatureDetector.ORB`.

I would like to specify the type of the FeatureDetector in a command line argument or in a configuration file. So basically I need to 'convert' the string `FeatureDetector.ORB` to the value of the field `FeatureDetector.ORB`.

So far I have been able to do it using reflection:

```
String detectorClassName = "ORB"; // the actual code gets the value from a Properties object
detectorClass = FeatureDetector.class;
Field f = detectorClass.getDeclaredField(detectorClassName);
int d = f.getInt(detectorClass);
detector = FeatureDetector.create(d);
```

, but I was wondering if there is a faster and easier way to accomplish it.

Comment: use enums and features they provide?

Comment: I would rather not use explicit numeric constants that might change in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java enums:

```
enum FeatureDetectorType {
    ORB(FeatureDetector.ORB),
    FOO(FeatureDetector.FOO),
    BAR(FeatureDetector.BAR);

    private final int detectorId;

    FeatureDetectorType(detectorId) {
        this.detectorId = detectorId;
    }

    public int getDetectorId() {
        return detectorId;
    }

}
```

And lookup enums by name like this:

```
FeatureDetectorType.valueOf("ORB").getDetectorId()
```

Comment: Your solution is elegant, but it requires to write an enumeration for each parameter you would like to pass as a string. Thank you.